# Is there any code generator for Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, code-generation

I tried a couple of web development frameworks, such as Zend Framework 1/2, Yii, Ruby on Rails, Django for Python, Spring+myBatis and so on. Most of them are shipped with a code generator which decrease the burden of writing CRUD, table data editing and SQL migrations (and so on). For example, Gii in Yii, Migration tools on ROR, myBatis generator for myBatis, Django app manager and so on. But I didn't find the same tool in ZF.

Is there anything useful for code generation in ZF2 with example features below:

1. Visual model generation (as in Gii);
2. Command Line SQL Generation and DB operation (as in Django);
3. Deployment script generation.

Comment: Looks like [Doctrine + Zend](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11513121/472495) is supported. Also, Propel comes with migrations support built-in, not sure about Doctrine. What ORM are you using?

Comment: @halfer Seems that Doctrine2 is a good choice, it's a bit close to myBatis. I may evaluate it more.

Comment: There is a Zend CLI tool, called [ZendTool](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html), for CRUD and application setup!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For ZF1, you can use Zodeken, it provide coplete crud interfaces. For zf2 is in developing.

https://code.google.com/p/zodeken/

https://code.google.com/p/zodeken2/

Comment: Bro, you're amazing! I would transfer all my reputation to you if i could. The tool you shared is for ZF1 what doctrine:mapping:import + doctrine:mapping:convert + doctrine:generate:entities + generate:doctrine:crud is for Symfony2. Thanks a lot for the share!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

The Zend Framework ships with the "Zend Framework Tool"

ZF2:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html

ZF 1.X:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html

With it you can initialize projects, add controllers, models, forms, etc. I have only used the ZF 1.X tool. It is handy for setting up the initial directory layout.

Comment: Thanks @Todd ! I know ZF tool and using it a little bit. But I think it's quite crude. I'm looking for something powerful.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit lower level than you may want, but there is a powerful package in ZF2 for code reflection, scanning and generation. In-house we use the Doctrine2 object manager to generate a full mvc stack from our Doctrine2 schema. Unfortunately, it's not very modular and I can't share the source with you directly. Here is the package:

http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/namespaces/Zend.Code.html

https://github.com/zendframework/Component_ZendCode

Pro tip 1: Use Twig, not phtml, for templating in your generator, because it's very hard to use phtml templates to write PHP...learned that the hard way :-/

Pro tip 2: The Scanner is very useful for reading code without having to instantiate it. This is handy for us, because we use a fail-safe in our generator, which says that if a file exists, it must contain a docblock annotation `@overwrite true` or it won't update that file. As such, we have to Scan every file before we output it. Reflection doesn't work for things like view scripts, but scanning works great!

Comment: Thanks for replying, @dualmon. I have read the api doc you mentioned in you reply. Is there any news that they will enhance the ZF_Tool to provide more powerful features?

Comment: I'm not sure about the plans for ZF_Tool, but FYI, Zend Studio has some support for ZF2. You can see a walkthrough of the features here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EerB9bTvqrY

(Note: this is not the workflow we use, so I can't speak to it from personal experience, but you might find it useful)

Answer (score 0):

For zend.framework 1 (ZF1) i already made a crud (code generator)
**zend-crud** . try it: https://magentoyan.com/zend-crud/

Answer (score -1):

This is a tool a friend of mine created, its made in java and it is very intuitive, if you had a question about how to use it let me know

https://bitbucket.org/Flavio378/jzftools/downloads/dist.zip